# php send message include check box array

Tags: php, html, message, checkbox

i want to make the php take productsq checkbox as array and send it in the message

this is not the code its just a part of it

this is the html part

`<input type="checkbox" id="productsq" name="productsq[]" value="cardprinter"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="productsq" name="productsq[]" value="hotelsolution"/ >`

this is the php part

```
<?php
    $productsqu= implode(',',mysql_real_escape_string($_post['productsq']));
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>products:</strong> 
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>comments:</strong> </td>    <td>" .clean_string($_POST['comments']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>selectionField:</strong> </td><td>" .clean_string($_POST['selectionField']) . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>products:</strong> </td><td>" .clean_string($productsqu) ."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
?>
```

i tried to use this one also but it didn't work is there a way to make it work properly ???

```
$productsqu= implode(',',mysql_real_escape_string($_post['productsq']));
```

Comment: i knew the solution
it works this way 

$productsq = implode(',',$_POST['productsq']);

Answer (score 0):

According to your checkboxes

`$_POST['productsq']` is an array.

```
$productsqu = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(", ", $_POST['productsq'])) ; //Implode into string first
```

So, first implode array into string and then use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

try below code hope it will help you.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) == 'submit')
{
         $productsqu= mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$_POST['productsq']));
         $message = '<html><body>';
         $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
         $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>products:</strong>";
         $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>comments:</strong> </td>    <td>" .$_POST['comments'] . "</td></tr>";
         $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>selectionField:</strong> </td><td>" .$_POST['selectionField']. "</td></tr>";
         $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>products:</strong> </td><td>" .$productsqu."</td></tr>";
         $message .= "</table>";
         $message .= "</body></html>";
     echo $message;
}   
?>
```

and there is also `";` missing in below line.

```
 $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>products:</strong>";
```